# Null-homotopic maps

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Assume that $[\alpha]\in\pi_n(X,x_0)$. I want to prove the following:

**$[\alpha]=0$ if and only if $\alpha:S^n\rightarrow X$ extends to a map $D^n\rightarrow X$.**

Can someone help me with this proof? Is this what some people call: $\alpha$ nullhomotopic iff it factors through $D^n$?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This follows from a more general statement that $f: Y \to X$ is nullhomotopic if and only if we can extend $f$ to a map $CY \to X$ where $CY$ is the cone on $Y$. I say this because the definition of a cone on $Y$ is easier to translate into a homotopy and vice versa. Then just observe that $CS^n  = D^{n}$

Comment: And why is tis statement true?

Comment: @JHance: How to construct the map $CY\rightarrow X$?.

Comment: Write down the definition of a map being homotopic to the constant map. Can you see how if a map $f\colon I\times Y\to Z$ has the property that $f(1,x)=f(1,x')$ for all $x,x'\in X$ then there exists map $g\colon CY\to Z$ such that $f=g\circ q\colon I\times Y\to CY\to Z$ where $q\colon I\times Y \to CY$ is the quotient map shrinking ${1}\times Y$ to a point?